# Chrome fails to decompress response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, sitecore, gzip, sitecore7.2

I've an issue where chrome renders the gzip response instead of decompressing it and render the page correctly. If I refresh the page it renders correctly.

I have only been able to reproduce this in chrome. Firefox, IE etc works fine.

I throught it was because of the null in the start of the headers, but if that was the case, then I would expect Firefox and other browsers to fail too.

It's fairly easy to reproduce on production. Simple refresh the page a little fast at this [website](http://www.wagner.dk)

I hope someone knows how to resolve this issue.

[image: Screenshot of chrome rendering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem. If anyone else is interested. This error was caused by Kaspersky antivirus.